# What is the difference between CentOS-6.0-i386-LiveDVD.iso and CentOS-6.0-i386-bin-DVD.iso

Tags: centos

What is the difference between CentOS-6.0-i386-LiveDVD.iso and CentOS-6.0-i386-bin-DVD.iso?

Comment: .. do you know what a [Live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) is? ... if not simply knowing this will tell you the difference.

Comment: Yes, I know a Live CD but I don't get it why there is a word 'bin' in the "CentOS-6.0-i386-bin-DVD.iso"? Would be better to call it "CentOS-6.0-i386-DVD.iso", right?

Comment: @ascobol, you question is referring to why CentOS is given the name 'CentOS' or you are referring to why I choose CentOS as the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LiveDVD will be bootable, and the other DVD contains the binaries required to install CentOS. There may sometimes be a cd labelled src which will contain the source code for the system.